# Fast Pochhammer

Tags: calculus, hypergeometric-function

I was wondering if there is a fast algorithm for the Pochhammer symbol?

$$(x)_n$$

...where n is very large?  e.g. $$n = 2^{160}$$

The implementations I've seen so far seem to use n additions/multiplies, which is out of the question with huge numbers.

Comment: It's an approximation, not a calculation, but [Stirling's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) is related.

Comment: What is the purpose of such calculations?

Comment: You intend $(x)_n=x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-n+1)$? That is $\frac{x!}{(x-n)!}$ and you can use [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: Hint: start with $\;\displaystyle x^{(n)}=\frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{\Gamma(x)}\;$ or $\;\displaystyle(x)_n=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x-n+1)}\;$ and use an approximation for the [$\log$ of $\Gamma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation#Stirling%27s_formula_for_the_gamma_function) (very useful for large values!).

Comment: Thanks all.  I will look at Stirling's approximation.  I was really hoping there would be something more accurate (read: exact)  
I guess that's still in open problem in maths for someone to solve.

Still, if anyone knows other algorithms that may help, please let me know.